# What is the correct translation of "My hovercraft is full of eels"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation

In the Monty Python sketch ["Dirty Hungarian phrasebook"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1Sw0PDgHU4), one of the English sentences erroneously translates to "My hovercraft is full of eels". Obviously, not a sentence you'd hear back in the days when Latin was widely spoken, but I'm still curious, how would one most correctly translate it into Latin?

The current working version I have is "Mea navis aëricumbens anguillis abundat", as per the [Wikipedia translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(M)).

Comment: "Obviously, not a sentence you'd hear back in the days when Latin was widely spoken" ← today, on everyone's lips?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Well, not on everyone's lips, but it's well known as a [trope](https://tropedia.fandom.com/wiki/My_Hovercraft_Is_Full_of_Eels), and finding translations of it in many languages is [something people do](https://omniglot.com/language/phrases/hovercraft.htm), since that's the original point of the sketch.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel There's an old [Omniglot](https://omniglot.com/language/phrases/hovercraft.htm) page on it. The Latin is different!

Comment: ...which I think is more accurate than Wikipedia: "Navis volitans mihi anguillis plena est."

Comment: @cmw *navis volitans* seems quite a strange description for a hovercraft.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I'm not sure if *volitans* has ever been used as an adjective (rather than a participle), but it can mean 'hover / float about.' I'm only glancing at the passages mentioned in Lewis and Short, but some do seem more 'float' than 'flutter.'

Answer (score 3):

I can sort of make out the Wikipedia version. It seems to be saying "my floating? boat is overflowing by means of/by/with eels." The only thing there is *aëricumbens*, which I can't exactly figure out. It looks like it a present participle with something to do with the air, but I can't find it in a dictionary.

The Lexicon Morganianum translates *hovercraft* as "scapha (automaria) Hoveriana." Hovercraft is not a Classical concept, to my knowledge, so I think *navis* is an adequate word for it, and, following this logic, *scapha* is also a fine word for it. I would choose the one that best fits the size you imagine your hovercraft being. If it is a small one, use *scapha*, but, if it is a large one, use *navis*. You could also do what some of your examples do and make hovercraft a construction with a participle. This would produce something such as *scapha volans* (the small, flying boat). Or maybe *scapha pendens* (the small, suspended/floating boat).

For "full of," I might lift a construction from Caesar. Caesar says that "Caesar, scaphas longarum navium, item speculatoria navigia militibus compleri iussit" (Gal. 4.26) and "cum fluctibus complerentur . . ." (Gal. 4.28). So I might suggest that you use *compleor* + abl.

For eels, I might suggest *anguilla*, which is the word used in the Wikipedia entry. You could use either *mea* or *mihi* to show possession. The former is the possessive pronoun (*my [boat]*), and the latter is the dative of possession (*[the boat] for/to me*).

When combined this gets you *scapha hoveriana mea anguillīs complētur* or *scapha pendens mihi angullīs complētur* or. You can, of course, change the word order to change the emphasis or rhythm.

Comment: To me, _aëricumbens_ looks like a transparent compound: it's a boat that rests (cumbere) on the air (aēr). Cumbere is an odd verb in that it's only normally found in compounds (recumbere, succumbere).

Comment: @Draconis Is *cumbere* actually attested? I don't see it in OLD, L&S, or searching PHI.

Comment: @cmw Not on its own, I don't think, but it appears in prefixed form often enough that I'm not surprised to see it in a compound. (I suppose _succuba_ and its ilk are evidence against that though.)

Comment: @Draconis Well, there's also [*cubare*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcubo).

Comment: @cmw Right; my understanding is that mostly displaced its cognate cumbo but didn't displace the compounds built off it.

Comment: @Draconis Just a guess here, but might *cumbere* be an example of a present nasal infix? If *cubare* weren't first conjugation, it would like very similar to a past tense of *cumbere*, like *λαμβάνω / λαβόν*.

Comment: (Not arguing with the displacement, just thinking about the history of both.)

Comment: @cmw That's my guess, though if we don't already have a question about that I should ask one.